# Imaging with radio Frequency

Tags: software-defined-radio, equipment-design, microwave

Is it possible to image bones and tissues with radio waves (2.7GHz-5GHz) with a tiny radio frequency source and on one side and a receiver on other side which can image the data through a PC mediated software (eg:with sdr) and printing out like an X-Ray ? (Not exactly, but similar to that)

Comment: Apparently. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_imaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a wavelength on the order of 10 cm, you might be able to use radar get some blurry inside imaging of very large beached whales (or maybe large dinosaurs, in conjunction with a suitable time machine).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, microwave imaging is a thing.

Technically, it's basically radar.

However, as always, your radar resolution is proportional to the bandwidth you're using and the carrier frequency (=inverse to the wavelength).

So, 2.7 GHz to 5 GHz is probably not going to give you a very nice spatial resolution, simply because their wavelengths are in the 6 to 11 cm region. Wave physics will make the body act like a non-uniform, wavelength scale body, leading to diffuse diffraction and refraction patterns.

So, the result will not be *anything* like X-Ray, where the wavelengths are far, far shorter than anything you'd want to image. Instead, you're setting yourself up for trying to solve a very high-dimensional, very complicated inverse problem for which, to my understanding of the matter, no unique solution exists if you just have a single emitter.

You could try very complicated synthetic aperture radar interferometric approaches to gain better resolution, but that would not completely solve the mathematical ambiguity.

Also, the effort you'll have to take in terms of measurement bandwidth, and oscillator coherency, will be pretty significant (as a matter of fact, I don't think I'd start implementing that without access to a Rubidium atomic clock).

So,

> Is it possible to image bones and tissues with radio waves (2.7GHz-5GHz)

Yes, in the > 10 k€ setup region, maybe,

> with a tiny radio frequency source

"tiny" is relative, and a single source won't do,

> a receiver on other side which can image the data through a PC mediated software (eg:with sdr) and printing out like an X-Ray

... assuming you have extensive knowledge in RF electronics, SDR, wave physics, and inverse problems as well as writing software, yes, maybe?

Comment: What is "k€"? Is that a typo?

Comment: no, 1 k€ = 10³ €.

Comment: So that is not a [Euro symbol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign), so what does it mean?

Comment: it is a Euro symbol! It means: If you spend more than ten thousand euros on your hardware setup (including Rubidium clock, and high-bandwidth SDR), then it might be possible.

Comment: Looks like a Euro symbol to me ... €

Comment: and it really is, @ScottEarle :)